# How to get access to the response from server within NSURLSessionDataTask called within failure block?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

For now the **failure** block within `AFNetworking`'s `POST` method is called. And there is access to `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

I need to access the response from server. I expect dictionary like this:

```
{ "error": "sth written on the backend" }
```

but I do not know where to looking for this? It was possible with `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and `AFNetworking 2.0`.

Using **AFNetworking 3.0**

Example:

```
POST("wishlists", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { sessionDataTask, response in

    }) { sessionDataTask, error in

            //here in failure block I need access to the response body
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is included in the `NSError` object:

```
if let responseData = error?.userInfo[NSString(string: AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey)] as? NSData {

    do {
        if let response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                //do sth with your response
        }

    } catch {
        //handle the exception
    }
}
```